# Getting ModuleNotFoundError only if debug mode is enabled

Tags: python, tensorflow, flask

I have a Flask server which loads `Tensorflow` models on startup in an external service module.

The problem is if debug mode is enabled, so `FLASK_DEBUG = 1`, the app crashes because it is not able to load a certain module from Tensorflow. `tensorflow_core.keras` to be precise.

However, running the application without debugging works.

The project structure looks like this:

```
controllers/
    __init__.py     # Exposes controllers_blueprint
    controller.py
services/
    service.py
__init__.py         # Exposes app, socketio
model_util.py       # Used to load models, imports Tensorflow
server.py
```

So, in a `services/service.py`, on module load, I call a function which does the job:

```py
import model_util

def _load_models():
    # Loading models here using model_util.load(..)
    return models


_models = _load_models()
```

This module gets imported from a `controllers/controller.py`

```py
from services import service
from flask import current_app, request
from application import socketio

NAMESPACE = '/test'

@socketio.on('connect', namespace=NAMESPACE)
def handle_connect():
    service.create_session(request.sid)
```

Where the `controllers/__init__.py` exposes a `controller_blueprint`:

```py
from flask import Blueprint
from controllers import controller

controllers_blueprint = Blueprint('controllers', __name__)
```

Which then gets registered in my `server.py`

```py
from flask import current_app

from controllers import controllers_blueprint
from application import app, socketio

def main():
    app.register_blueprint(controllers_blueprint)
    socketio.run(app)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

For completeness, this is `__init__.py`

```py
from flask import Flask
from flask_caching import Cache
from flask_socketio import SocketIO


HTTP_SERVER_PORT = 5000

app = Flask(__name__, static_folder='../static', static_url_path='')

cache = Cache(config={'CACHE_TYPE': 'simple'})
cache.init_app(app)

socketio = SocketIO(app)
socketio.init_app(app)
```

Also `model_util.py` is where the Tensorflow modules are being imported:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
from tensor2tensor.data_generators.text_encoder import SubwordTextEncoder
# ...

def load(...):
   # ..
   pass
```

The error I am getting is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/sfalk/miniconda3/envs/web-service/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "/Users/sfalk/miniconda3/envs/web-service/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/Users/sfalk/miniconda3/envs/web-service/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/__main__.py", line 15, in <module>
    main(as_module=True)
  File "/Users/sfalk/miniconda3/envs/web-service/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 967, in main
    cli.main(args=sys.argv[1:], prog_name="python -m flask" if as_module else None)
  File "/Users/sfalk/miniconda3/envs/web-service/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 586, in main
    return super(FlaskGroup, self).main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/sfalk/miniconda3/envs/web-service/lib/python3.7/site-packages/click/core.py", line 782, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "/Users/sfalk/miniconda3/envs/web-service/lib/python3.7/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1259, in invoke
    return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
  File "/Users/sfalk/miniconda3/envs/web-service/lib/python3.7/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1066, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
  File "/Users/sfalk/miniconda3/envs/web-service/lib/python3.7/site-packages/click/core.py", line 610, in invoke
    return callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/sfalk/miniconda3/envs/web-service/lib/python3.7/site-packages/click/decorators.py", line 73, in new_func
    return ctx.invoke(f, obj, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/sfalk/miniconda3/envs/web-service/lib/python3.7/site-packages/click/core.py", line 610, in invoke
    return callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/sfalk/miniconda3/envs/web-service/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 860, in run_command
    extra_files=extra_files,
  File "/Users/sfalk/miniconda3/envs/web-service/lib/python3.7/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 1050, in run_simple
    run_with_reloader(inner, extra_files, reloader_interval, reloader_type)
  File "/Users/sfalk/miniconda3/envs/web-service/lib/python3.7/site-packages/werkzeug/_reloader.py", line 337, in run_with_reloader
    reloader.run()
  File "/Users/sfalk/miniconda3/envs/web-service/lib/python3.7/site-packages/werkzeug/_reloader.py", line 202, in run
    for filename in chain(_iter_module_files(), self.extra_files):
  File "/Users/sfalk/miniconda3/envs/web-service/lib/python3.7/site-packages/werkzeug/_reloader.py", line 24, in _iter_module_files
    filename = getattr(module, "__file__", None)
  File "/Users/sfalk/miniconda3/envs/web-service/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 50, in __getattr__
    module = self._load()
  File "/Users/sfalk/miniconda3/envs/web-service/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 44, in _load
    module = _importlib.import_module(self.__name__)
  File "/Users/sfalk/miniconda3/envs/web-service/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 965, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow_core.keras'
```

What is the reason for this and how can I resolve this issue?

#### Additional Information

I am running the application with PyCharm. This is the output on startup:

```
FLASK_APP = application/server.py
FLASK_ENV = development
FLASK_DEBUG = 1
In folder /Users/sfalk/workspaces/git/web-service
/Users/sfalk/miniconda3/envs/web-service/bin/python -m flask run
 * Serving Flask app "application/server.py" (lazy loading)
 * Environment: development
 * Debug mode: on
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
 * Restarting with stat
 * Debugger is active!
 * Debugger PIN: 298-908-268
```

Comment: Where exactly do you import the modules? In `services/service.py`?

Comment: @Erich Yes, I added this to the code (see edit). I basically import a `model_util` module which is where the tensorflow modules are being imported

Comment: How do you run your app? With `python3 -m`?

Comment: @Erich I am running it from within PyCharm. I edited my question. It seems that his gets executed with `python -m flask run`.

Comment: Can you try running it manually with `python3` without `-m` option? There seems to be a bug in `werkzeug` with the `-m` option: https://github.com/pallets/werkzeug/issues/461

Comment: @Erich Ok I ran it with `FLASK_APP=application FLASK_DEBUG=1 flask run` and it does not crash. However, the static content it not loaded now?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212410/discussion-between-erich-and-displayname).

Comment: @Erich So, your suggestion was the solution in the end. I just had to use a Python fun configuration instead of the Flask Server configuration in PyCharm.

Comment: I post an answer later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently there is a [bug](https://github.com/pallets/werkzeug/issues/461) in `werkzeug` which is used by `flask` to serve `flask` apps, when running `flask` apps in debug mode with `python -m`.

To prevent this from happening, you can start the app without the `-m` option, e.g with `flask run`.

Comment: I am getting exactly the error from the original question (same module and everything), but I am using flask run. As with the original asker, it's only happening when setting FLASK_ENV to development.

Comment: To answer myself, it is a known issue that has been solved in Tensorflow 2.2